# hide border-bottom after clicked the button

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I have created a button. I want that when I clicked the button, the button border-bottom will hide. How can I do that with CSS? I have attached the image also. Please help and check attached image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNuLh.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSjbn.jpg)

i try active, focus and visited on button but still not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to hide the button border when it is clicked and show it if it is unselected then you can use `:focus`.

`.button:focus { border-bottom: 0; }`

However if you need it to always be hidden after the click you will need to use javascript.

```
function HideBorder() {
   document.getElementById("button").borderBottom = "0px";
}
```

```
<button id="button" onclick="HideBorder()"></button>
```

Comment: I used the focus but it's not working. I want to hide the border-bottom whenever user clicked on the button like as shown in the 2nd screenshot and if the user clicked the button again then the button should returned to the default state.